# power automate can you make a drop down input with dynamic values

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

Fairly simple question I have a power automate flow with a `for selected file` trigger one of the inputs is a dropdown is there any way to create this dropdown to have values based on a dropdown that is in the SharePoint document library the file is in?

[image]

this should be populated by these values

[image]

Comment: Show us a screenshot.

Comment: @Skin added some

Comment: Still a little confused, looks like manual trigger (button) options but it’s not the same icon. Can you provide more context? Maybe a screenshot with additional information on the outside of what you’ve already provided?